# What is the topic path in microsoft service bus?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

For this method:

```
public static SubscriptionClient CreateFromConnectionString(string connectionString, string topicPath, string name)
```

What is the topicPath?

MSDN says it is "The full pathname of the topic."

What is the pathname?

There are code examples, but I have yet to find one that explain this little detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topic path is the same string that was used as topic's name to create it. See examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions

Note ASB names are subject to some limitations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas

Comment: In the new `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` libraries, there's now a `EntityNameHelper` class that will create these path names for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question looking for the path to the subscription.  When using a `MessageReceiver`, the subscription path is:

**`{topicName}/subscriptions/{subscriptionName}`**

So for just the topic path it should be simply

**`{topicName}`**